# Append bytes to NSMutableData in Swift

Tags: swift

In Obj-C I can successfully append bytes enclosed inside two quotation marks like so:

```
[commands appendBytes:"\x1b\x61\x01"
                   length:sizeof("\x1b\x61\x01") - 1];
```

In Swift I supposed I would do something like:

```
commands.appendBytes("\x1b\x61\x01", length: sizeof("\x1b\x61\x01") - 1)
```

But this throws the error "invalid escape sequence in literal", how do I escape bytes in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said, in Swift a string stores Unicode characters, and not – as in (Objective-)C – an arbitrary (NUL-terminated) sequence of `char`, which is a signed
or unsigned byte on most platforms.

Now theoretically you can retrieve a C string from a Swift string:

```
let commands = NSMutableData()
let cmd = "\u{1b}\u{61}\u{01}"
cmd.withCString {
    commands.appendBytes($0, length: 3)
}
println(commands) // <1b6101>
```

But this produces not the expected result for all non-ASCII characters:

```
let commands = NSMutableData()
let cmd = "\u{1b}\u{c4}\u{01}"
cmd.withCString {
    commands.appendBytes($0, length: 3)
}
println(commands) // <1bc384>
```

Here `\u{c4}` is "Ä" which has the UTF-8 representation `C3 84`.

A Swift string *cannot* represent an arbitrary sequence of bytes.
Therefore you better work with an `UInt8` array for (binary) control sequences:

```
let commands = NSMutableData()
let cmd : [UInt8] = [ 0x1b, 0x61, 0xc4, 0x01 ]
commands.appendBytes(cmd, length: cmd.count)
println(commands) // <1b61c401>
```

For *text* you have to know which encoding the printer expects.
As an example, `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` is the [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1) encoding, which is intended for "Western European" languages:

```
let text = "123Ö\n"
if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSISOLatin1StringEncoding) {
    commands.appendData(data)
    println(commands) // 313233d6 0a>
} else {
    println("conversion failed")
}
```

Comment: Got it, if I would want to input an Ä with other text i guess i would do it like this?  commands.appendData("Test\nAddress\n\u{c384}rtor\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!) but the printer actually prints 8Ää (8 on its side) why is that?

Comment: @SamPettersson: In a Swift string you can simply write "Ä", or equivalently "\u{c4}". \u{c384} represents the Unicode code point U+C384 = HANGUL SYLLABLE SSE = 쎄. The UTF-8 representation of that character is `EC 8E 84` ... - For a more specific answer we need to know exactly which byte sequence is expected by the printer to print an "Ä", in particular which encoding should be used for the character.

Comment: if I write Ä in my string i get a character which looks like |-ä?

Comment: @SamPettersson: Sorry, but that is too vague. Can you update your question with the exact code and the expected and actual result? Or is this a different question?

Comment: Basically I can send the printer a string of characters with the appendData function of NSMutableData, if I send "Test123\u{D6}\n" where D6 is the ASCII hex for Ö I get this http://imgur.com/ba6ynZb

Comment: @SamPettersson: \u{D6} converted to UTF-8 is `C3 96`. I do not know the specification of your printer, so I cannot guess what it expects, perhaps some ISO encoding instead of UTF-8.

Comment: @SamPettersson: I have updated the answer, perhaps that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62893/discussion-between-sam-pettersson-and-martin-r).

Answer (score 1):

Unicode characters in Swift are entered differently - you need to add curly braces around the hex number:

```
"\u{1b}\u{61}\u{01}"
```

To avoid duplicating the literal, define a constant for it:

```
let toAppend = "\u{1b}\u{61}\u{01}"
commands.appendBytes(toAppend, length: toAppend.length - 1)
```

Comment: sizeof doesn't seem to work with the type toAppend has, the error "'String' is not convertible to 'T.Type'" is thrown.